# cannot remove 'known_hosts': operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, files, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I am having problems with my remmina remote desktop and I've been searching online how to fix it. As mentioned [here](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/remmina-cannot-connect-to-rdp-server/) and in other posts on this forum, one suggestion is to try:

rm ~/.freerdp/known_hosts

However, I get the following error:

rm: cannot remove 'known_hosts': Operation not permitted

Even using sudo rm doesn't resolve the issue. Any suggestions how to get around this?

Edit: I forgot to add that doing ls -l on this file gives me:

-rw-rw-r-- 1 my_name my_name

Edit: Also, if it helps, I previously applied

sudo chattr +i ~/.freerdp/known_hosts

based on a previous suggestion.

Comment: As you applied `chattr +i` you should be aware of what it means and how to revert it. Or you just copy-pasted some command from the internet that you don't know and did not read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start as root, in the terminal write:

sudo -s

And type the password you used when configuring ubuntu in your installation.
If it went well, you would have changed the $ for #
Then try to execute the rm again.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It says operation not permitted.

Comment: By using the command are you using the spaces as samples in your explanation? because the spaces between ~/ and .freerdp/known_hosts are not used.
Apart from "operation not permited", do you get anything else?

Comment: Using the chattr + i command makes the files you indicate untouchable. To remove it you simply have to change the + to - .Once this is done try the rm again

Comment: Thanks! I just applied chattr -i and am now able to remove the file